# Has Anyone Migrate a Site from CraftCMS to ExpressionEngine?

Tags: ee5

Are there any 'How-To Guides' on switching from a Craft 2 site to ExpressionEngine?

I sit on a committee, where their developer switched them to Craft 2 maybe 5 years ago. Unfortunately, it is poorly set-up and the group that set-up no longer supports it. I've been helping them add new templates, adjust code, and make minor/medium changes, but have reached my limit in terms of being able to tell what's a restriction/limitation introduced by the original developer and their set-up versus the software.

I'm exploring what a clean install of Craft 3 might offer, as well as just moving them to ExpressionEngine 5, which I prefer. But it's for them not me. So far, everything I find is migrating from EE2 to Craft 2 or Craft 3 (which makes sense, since that was the great migration period).

But EE5 is superior to Craft 2 and on par with Craft 3, so I'm hoping someone has made the switch and has some ideas around best practices.

Comment: I don't want to start a flame war, but I don't think you'd find many people that agree that EE5 is "on par" with Craft 3... There's a reason that migrations tend to happen in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

I've not done a Craft to EE migration but the process is the same from any system.

I'd first get your Craft data into an exportable format then use EE's Datagrab addon to import data - https://expressionengine.com/add-ons/datagrab - I normally use XML where complex data structures are involved.

Obviously you'd need to set up EE channels/fields first so you can match your data sets.

Might be a good idea to set up a test EE install so you can test data imports and iron out any quirks before you commit to your development site.